# Grafana filter by name Zabbix query , but by variable

Tags: grafana, zabbix, grafana-variable

How can I somehow make this work?

I have a grafana panel which gets data from Zabbix SQL query, then I extract these dates.

My table looks like:

```
x | y | z
--+---+--
1 | 2 | 3
```

I want to get back only the value 1, if my variable is set to x, on the dashboard.

Any tips or tricks for problems like this?

Another same problem, to show the variable itself as a TEXT somehow, not by a text box, because it looks lame and small. I want a proper like stat panel, not setting everything but value mapping the null value into the variable itself, so it shows it nice.

Thanks for your help.

I already tried for the first problem:

Zabbix query text filter, filter by name by variable, itemtag, none of them worked out.

For the second problem I tried value mapping with `$var`, didn't work.